# substring (java) doesn't work as i expected

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

I have a code that should take off 2 elements from a string. Works OK with alphanumerics, but when i entered a string of the same number, i.e, just "1": (111111111), returns me nothing or just "1" or something very different from what i expected.

Here's my code:

```
String str= "222222222";
System.out.println(str.replace(str.substring(3, 5), ""));           }
```

in this case, returns "2", but 
if the string is with one "2" less, returns nothing

I apreciate your help :)

Comment: that's expected isn't it? what do you expect instead?

Comment: `str.substring(3,5)` is `"22"`. So you're replacing every `"22"` with `""`

Comment: ... and since there is a odd number of 2's, you're left with one unmatched `"2"`

Comment: Perhaps you should **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`replace(target, replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: This was definitely a logic problem.
I'll go straight to javadoc
Thank you all, people

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `str` is `"222222222"`, then `str.substring(3,5)` is `"22"`. So you're calling `str.replace("22", "")`, which replaces **every** `"22"` with `""`.

If you want to excise a fragment of a string, you can just pick out the rest using `substring`.

```
System.out.println(str.substring(0,3) + str.substring(5));
```

Alternatively, `StringBuilder` has a [`delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)) method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.delete(3,5);
System.out.println(sb);
```

You can use `sb.toString()` to convert the `StringBuilder` back to a string.